# Hide / Change WooCommerce admin notice

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, hook-wordpress

Hi WooCommerce ninjas!

I'm developing WooCommerce plugin and every time when I submit form (Save Changes button) on top shows update notice with 'Your settings have been saved.'. How I can hide or change this notice, I'm use `woocommerce_show_admin_notice` filter but don't work in my plugin class. Below is part of code from my plugin. Any ideas for hook who will be usefull?

Great thanks!

```
<?php 
class name_of_plugin extends WC_Payment_Gateway {
   public $error = '';

   // Setup our Gateway's id, description and other values
   function __construct() {
    $this->id = "name_of_plugin";
    $this->method_title = __( "Name", 'domain' );
    $this->method_description = __( "Gateway Plug-in for WooCommerce", 'domain' );
    $this->title = __( "TFS VPOS", 'domain' );
    $this->icon = null;
    $this->has_fields = false;
    $this->init_settings();
    $this->init_form_fields();
    $this->title = $this->get_option( 'title' );


    $this->testurl = 'https://example.com/payment/api';
    $this->liveurl = 'https://example.com/payment/api';


    // Save settings
    if ( is_admin()) {
        add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_payment_gateways_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'process_admin_options' ) );
    }

    // Disable Admin Notice
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_show_admin_notice', array( $this, 'shapeSpace_custom_admin_notice' ), 10, 2 );
    // add the filter 
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_error', array( $this, 'filter_woocommerce_add_notice_type' ), 10, 1 ); 

   } // End __construct()

  // display custom admin notice
  public function filter_woocommerce_add_notice_type($true, $notice ) {
    // magic happen here...
    return $true;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see any proper hook that can be used to remove this.

But these 2 seems to work.

My first thought is to reload the page so the settings text will be gone at the time. Something like this.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_sections_checkout', 'woocommerce_sections_checkout' );
function woocommerce_sections_checkout() {

    if ( isset( $_GET['section'] ) && isset( $_REQUEST['_wpnonce'] ) && ( $_GET['section'] === 'paypal' ) 
        && wp_verify_nonce( $_REQUEST['_wpnonce'], 'woocommerce-settings' ) ) {

        WC_Admin_Settings::add_message( __( 'Your settings have been saved!', 'woocommerce' ) );
        wp_safe_redirect( wp_get_raw_referer() );
        exit();
    }
}
```

Then my second option is if you wanted to change the text, we can use the filter gettext.

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'woocommerce_save_settings_text', 20, 3 );
function woocommerce_save_settings_text( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {

    if ( ( $domain == 'woocommerce' ) && isset( $_GET['section'] ) && ( $_GET['section'] === 'paypal' ) ) {
        switch ( $translated_text ) {
            case 'Your settings have been saved.' :
                $translated_text = __( 'Your awesome settings have been saved.', 'woocommerce' );
                break;
        }
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
```

Please do note that this code is just an example and will work for paypal settings. Change everything that is needed.

Comment: Thanks for helping @Reigel, actually I use css for hide unuseful section and then extended `display_notice` method for drawing errors.